# How to combine a responsive Qt GUI with an OpenMP based computation library?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, openmp

Our software consists of a Graphical User Interface in C++/Qt. The user interface controls several heavy computational algorithms in a separate library which uses C++/OpenMP for parallelization. In this library we cannot use Qt.

To keep our GUI responsive we use function pointers which call `QApplication::processEvents();`. This of course leads to spaghetti code. We would like to separate the GUI from the computation library, so that the function calls do not block the GUI any longer. What is the clean and prefered way to do this?

Comment: with "keep our GUI responsive", do you mean to be able to interrupt any running openMP code?

Comment: I want that the Qt event loop is not blocked when the openMP code in the other library runs. In that case the GUI would be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to interrupt the openMP library calls, then I would go for a simple multi-threading approach: one thread deals with the GUI, another with the computational library. Naturally you cannot use openMP for this (this would not fare well with the computational openMP library), but must use other multi-threading methods. C++11 now comes with its own direct support of threads, so that's what I would do.

EDIT: read Anthony Williams "C++ concurrency in action"

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? Can't I start a new thread from the Qt main thread and let it do computations using OpenMP? Please note: I did't read the book in the meantime. Thanks for the pointer, though.

Comment: that should work (who said it wouldn't?) You cannot use openMP to split the work, since all current implementations don't really do nested parallel regions.

Comment: Okay, sorry I misinterpreted the 'this would not fare well' part.

Answer (score 0):

`QApplication` launches control loop, which calls GUI methods. Naturally, any method taking long will block the queue. To prevent this, you need to spawn additional process/thread via `fork`/`QThread`. I think the `QThread` approach would be the cleanest way to acomplish your goal

Comment: So you mean the following? I should start a thread worker from the Qt GUI. The worker is able to start computations without blocking the GUI. My GUI calls are then send via the worker. Communication between GUI and worker should then be done with signal->slot connections.